# Selenium syntax difference on different resources - Why is this

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have been working with selenium and consulting different helping resources for error solving. I have seen that sometimes, there is a slight difference in the syntax of the locators used.

This is what I am currently using.

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "id")
```

But I have also seen this being used sometimes:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("id")
```

Can you please explain the difference.

I am using the following syntax but curios why is there a different syntax as well.

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "id")
```

Comment: The different syntaxes are from different versions of Selenium.

Comment: ... and this is why you should be consulting the official document for the latest version(*) of Selenium rather than  relying on "random" sources that Google found for you. (* - or for the specific version you are using).  Remember: the internet has no quality control.

Comment: Yeah, been thinking that. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

### Selenium documentation is scattered and inconsistent with versions

Because Selenium is open source, many documentation sources, articles, demos, etc., tend to reference different syntax based on the version that was available at that time.

[Finding selectors by GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-find_element_by_id-method-in-selenium/) was published in 2022.

`find_element_by_` methods were deprecated as part of Selenium v4.3 in 2022: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/10712

### For reference, we're on Selenium v4.18

For the official API docs, visit [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html#webdriver-chrome), select the `webdriver` you're using, and you'll find all the methods associated with it.

For example, [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver) is where you'll find all the `selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver` methods, notably the
`find_element(By.ID, 'foo')` method that you reference

Comment: Thnaks, its helpful